# DOMPDF no me admite algunos caracteres

Tags: php, dompdf

Estoy generando PDFs desde un contenido HTML mediante la librería DOMPDF.

Lo que ocurre es que necesito caracteres como estos:

- ℣
- ℟

Sin embargo el PDF no los reconoce, me los cambia por el signo `?`

Mi HTML se crea bien y tiene la codificación correcta, por ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lecturas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <font color="red"><b>≡ PRIMERA LECTURA</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jb 19, 21-27<br /><br /></font>Del libro de Job<br /><br />
  <font color="red">Yo sé que está vivo mi Vengador</font><br /><br />Dijo Job: <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;«¡Piedad, piedad, amigos míos, <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;que me ha herido la mano de Dios! <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;¿Por qué me
  perseguís como Dios <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;y no os hartáis de escarnecerme? <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Ojalá se escribieran mis palabras! <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Ojalá se grabaran en cobre, <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;con
  cincel de hierro y con plomo <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;se escribieran para siempre en la roca! <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yo sé que mi redentor vive <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;y que al fin se alzará sobre el polvo:
  <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;después que me arranquen la piel, <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ya sin carne, veré a Dios. <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yo mismo lo veré, y no otro; <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;mis
  propios ojos lo verán. <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Tal ansia me consume por dentro!<br /><br />
  <font color="red"><b>≡ SALMO</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sal 26, 7-8a. 8b-9abc. 13-14<br /><br /></font>Salmo<br /><br />
  <font color="red">Espero gozar de la dicha del Señor en el país de la vida</font><br /><br />
  <font color="red">℣. </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Escúchame, Señor,<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;que te llamo;<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ten piedad, respóndeme.<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Oigo en mi corazón:<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;«Buscad
  mi rostro».
  <font color="red"> ℟.</font><br /><br />
  <font color="red">℣. </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tu rostro buscaré, Señor,<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no me escondas tu rostro.<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No rechaces con ira a tu siervo,<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;que tú
  eres mi auxilio;<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no me deseches.
  <font color="red"> ℟.</font><br /><br />
  <font color="red">℣. </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Espero gozar de la dicha del Señor<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;en el país de la vida.<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Espera en el Señor, sé valiente,<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ten
  ánimo, espera en el Señor.
  <font color="red"> ℟.</font><br /><br />
  <font color="red"><b><br />≡ EVANGELIO</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lc 10, 1-12<br /><br /></font>Del Santo Evangelio según san Lucas<br /><br />
  <font color="red">Vuestra paz descansará sobre ellos</font><br /><br />En aquel tiempo, designó el Señor otros setenta y dos, y los mandó delante de él, de dos en dos, a todos los pueblos y lugares adonde pensaba ir él. <br /><br />Y les decía: <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;«La
  mies es abundante y los obreros pocos; rogad, pues, al dueño de la mies que envíe obreros a su mies. <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Poneos en camino! Mirad que os envío como corderos en medio de lobos. No llevéis bolsa, ni alforja, ni sandalias;
  y no saludéis a nadie por el camino. <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cuando entréis en una casa, decid primero: “Paz a esta casa”. Y si allí hay gente de paz, descansará sobre ellos vuestra paz; si no, volverá a vosotros. Quedaos en la misma casa,
  comiendo y bebiendo de lo que tengan: porque el obrero merece su salario. No andéis cambiando de casa en casa. <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Si entráis en una ciudad y os reciben, comed lo que os pongan, curad a los enfermos que haya en ella,
  y decidles: “El reino de Dios ha llegado a vosotros”. <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pero si entráis en una ciudad y no os reciben, saliendo a sus plazas, decid: “Hasta el polvo de vuestra ciudad, que se nos ha pegado a los pies, nos lo sacudimos
  sobre vosotros. De todos modos, sabed que el reino de Dios ha llegado”. <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Os digo que aquel día será más llevadero para Sodoma que para esa ciudad.<br /><br /><small><center>Textos litúrgicos oficiales<br /><font color="red">©</font> Conferencia Episcopal Española</center></small></body>

</html>
```

Pero en el PDF como digo, me cambia esos caracteres por `?`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código PHP donde genero el PDF (estoy usando `cURL`):

```
function get_pdf($url,$dompdf) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $dompdf->load_html($r);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("test.pdf", array('Attachment'=>'0'));
}
```

**¿Conocen alguna forma de mostrar esos caracteres especiales?**

Comment: puedes usar caracters ascii y asegúrate que tengas el meta de `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: @Cig el meta lo tengo bien, de hecho con los acentos no hay problemas, es con los caracteres especiales como `℣`. ¿Dónde sugieres que use caracteres ASCII?

Comment: @A.Cedano, específicamente en ese caracter que te pone el signo de interrogación, `&#8483;` me parece que es ese. https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_letterlike.asp

Comment: Es correcto @Cig, es el caracter `&#8483;`. Hice una prueba cambiando `℣` por `&#8483;` en el HTML, pero pasa lo mismo, me lo cambia por `?`.

Comment: Gracias por el enlace @Trauma, voy a revisar y comento...

Comment: ¿Que versión de php utilizas? aparte como comenta @Trauma puede que también sea problema de las fuentes. Me paso a mi con el simbolo de Euros, completa bien la etiqueta meta y si tu versión es igual o mayor a la 0.6 puedes utilizar `body { font-family: "DejaVu Sans", sans; }`

Comment: @Cig estoy usando PHP 5.6. La etiqueta `meta` está bien bien así, recuerdo haber leído que poner la etiqueta meta así: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` ya es obsoleto. En HTML5 se recomienda poner simplemente esto: `<meta charset="utf-8">`, tal y como lo tengo. Como ya comenté, no tengo problemas con el charset, porque los acentos se muestran bien.

Comment: Si, es lo que veo de la etiqueda, sigo en la prehistoria. Intenta con el css que te puse, también puede que sea es. si es que tienes la versión mas actual de dompdf.

Comment: @Cig le puse lo que me dijiste: `<style>
 body 
 {
  font-family: "DejaVu Sans", sans;

 }
</style>`  y ahora sí muestra los caracteres correctamente :-)  ¿Sabes si hay otras fuentes que sean compatibles, o estoy obligado a usar solamente esa?

Comment: *Dompdf* no incluye fuentes con caracteres especiales como los que tratas de utilizar, si no especificas una fuente, entonces dompdf recurre a una de las fuentes principales (Helvetica, Times Roman, Courier) que solo admite la codificación ANSI de Windows. Por lo tanto, asegurate siempre de aplicar estilo a tus textos con una fuente que admita la codificación Unicode y que tenga los caracteres que necesita mostrar. Y pues "Dejavi Sans" ya la incluye dompdf que si admite codificación UNICODE

Comment: @Cig entendido. Propongo que coloques una respuesta con la solución. Gracias por todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para tu problema:

**Dompdf** no incluye fuentes con caracteres especiales por defecto como los que tratas de utilizar. **Si no especificas una fuente**, entonces **dompdf recurre a una de las fuentes principales (Helvetica, Times Roman, Courier)** que solo admite la codificación **ANSI de Windows**.

Por lo tanto, asegúrate siempre de aplicar estilo a tus textos con una fuente que admita la codificación Unicode y que tenga los caracteres que necesita mostrar.

```
<style>
  body { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }
</style>
```

Por ejemplo la fuente **DejaVu Sans** ya la trae dompdf, esta si acepta caracteres unicode.